# How to stop the playing of a sound in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

When playing a sound I would like to have the possibility to stop this with another button. Or when pressing the play button again, the playing of the sound should stop, and then played from the beginning.

I struggled implementing this in R Shiny using shinyjs but did not succeed. This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

  shiny::actionButton('sound'  ,'Play sound'),
  shiny::actionButton('stopper','Stop sound')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$sound, 
  {
    shinyjs::runjs("snd.pause();")
    shinyjs::runjs("var snd = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3'); snd.play();")
  })

  observeEvent(input$stopper, 
  {
    shinyjs::runjs("snd.pause();")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code is inspired by the code at: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-stop-audio-with-shinyjs/122650.

So the idea is that after pressing the 'Play sound' button the play can be stopped prematurely with the 'Stop sound' button, or when prematurely pressing the 'Play sound' button the playing should stop and subsequently start from the beginning.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is very easy, you need to define `snd` globally before you call in `shinyjs`, instead of directly defining it in the `shinyjs`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    
    shiny::actionButton('sound'  ,'Play sound'),
    shiny::actionButton('stopper','Stop sound'),
    tags$script("var snd;")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$sound, 
                 {
                     shinyjs::runjs("snd.pause();")
                     shinyjs::runjs("snd = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3'); snd.play();")
                 })
    
    observeEvent(input$stopper, 
                 {
                     shinyjs::runjs("snd.pause();")
                 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The reason is each `runjs` is inside different function call scope; when you want to use `snd` in another `runjs`, it is `undefined` because current scope or parent scopes do not have this variable, so you want to define it globally first. You may want to search for more details on how scoping works in JS.